# PHP & MySQL: Insert select result into table with id auto_increment

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to assign an ID number to each group I create from userInformation and save into groupInformation. I keep getting the error:

> Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I am unsure if I should increment the groupId. If by php or mysql. It was suggested to me to created an array to increment the groupId, but I do not know how to start that.

My Table are:

GroupInformation = GroupId(primary key, auto_increment), RegistrationId (foreign key)

UserInformation = RegistrationId(primary key, auto_increment), Name, Email, Address

```
$GroupSize = $_POST['groupsize'];

$con = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbName) or die("Nope");

if (isset($_POST['create'])) {

//assign group id to groups created
//insert RegistrationId into groupinformation from records randomly selected from userInformation,  group Id must increment by every group created in groupinformation

//$query ="Select RegistrationId from userInformation order by RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize;
   $query = "INSERT INTO groupInformation SELECT RegistrationId FROM (SELECT RegistrationId FROM userInformation ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") as res";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die ("query failed " . mysqli_error($con));


//unsure how to use this array
    while (($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) == true) {
        echo $row[0].'<br>';

    }
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html can be useful

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

$query = "INSERT INTO groupInformation (RegistrationId ) SELECT RegistrationId FROM (SELECT RegistrationId FROM userInformation ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ".$GroupSize.") as res";

Comment: I tried that but each member gets a different group Id I need the same group Id